# overflow: hidden of absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've read all the similar examples and still cannot get the right solution.

Basically I have a simple Side Menu which toggles on button click. In the menu there is a list of checkboxes (their position is absolute). The parent container seems to be positioned relatively. Please help me to find the solution so that "overflow: hidden" would word.

I tried to simplify the code below. The working example of the whole app is posted here(it's easier to see the problem): https://arturtakoev.github.io/redux-reader/

And one additional question: I've noticed that the animation significantly slows down when there is a content on the page. This only appears on the deployed version and works fine on local one. Do you know why?

JS (jsx):

```
const SideMenu = ({ onClick, selectedSources, onSelectAll, onUnselectAll, showMenu }) => {



    const listOfSources = Object.keys(selectedSources).map(key => key)
    function renderSources() {
        return listOfSources.map((source) => (
            <li>
                <a onClick={(e) => onClick(e, [source])}>{source}</a>
            </li>
        ))
    }

    function renderSourcesChecks() {
        return listOfSources.map((source) => (
            <div className="relative">
            <li>
                <label className="containerOne" style={selectedSources[source].isSelected ? { color: sourceActiveColor } : { color: sourceNotActiveColot }}>{selectedSources[source].properties.title}
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => onClick(e, [source])} checked={selectedSources[source].isSelected} />
                    <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
            </div>
        ))
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <nav id="sidebar" className={showMenu.isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
        <ul className="list-unstyled components">
            <div>
                <h3>
                    <a onClick={(e) => onSelectAll(e, listOfSources)}>
                        <img id="icon" src={require('../assets/newsIcon.png')} className="d-inline-block align-top" />
                        All in one
                    </a>
                    <a onClick={(e) => onUnselectAll(e, listOfSources)} id="closeicon" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </a>
                </h3>

            </div>
            {renderSourcesChecks()}
        </ul>
        </nav>        
        </div>
    )
};
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* top layer */
    z-index: 9999;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
#sidebar.visible {
    width: 250px;
}
#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 8px 8px 15px;

    cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* The container */
.containerOne {
    display: block;
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.containerOne input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.containerOne .checkmark:after {
    left: 7px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 13px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: which element you want to make `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what are you trying to achieve. Can you please try and clarify your problem? try reading [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Zuber to the list in the side menu. As you can see in the example, during the animation it is breaking down. The fixed width helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get your question exactly but if you want the list will not break when collapsing simply give the "#sidebar ul.components" a fixed width like 250px; so text will not break.
Let me know if you need something else.